# How animate a view in with a flip animation

Tags: iphone, objective-c

This is my current code, but it seems to just be flipping the view - I want it to flip-in i.e. flip for not seeing it to seeing it.  I am doing this in the viewdidload method:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.5 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionOverrideInheritedDuration animations:^{
        [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:self.alertView cache:YES];

    }completion:^(BOOL finished)
     {

     }];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `transitionFromView:toView:duration:options:completion:` method with a full transpatent view as 'FromView' and your `alertView` as `toView`